# Presence return always available

Tags: android, openfire, smack

I am able to get all registered users from openfire, but unable to get status of all users. I have tried the below code but it returns available all time whether that user online or offline. Please help me to get status of all users. Any suggestion acceptable.

```
try
        {
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            myXMPP.getConnection().login(username, password);

            UserSearchManager usm = new UserSearchManager(myXMPP.getConnection());

            Form searchForm = usm.getSearchForm("search." + myXMPP.getConnection().getServiceName());
            Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();
            UserSearch userSearch = new UserSearch();
            answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);
            answerForm.setAnswer("search", "*");
            ReportedData data = userSearch.sendSearchForm(myXMPP.getConnection(), answerForm, "search." + myXMPP.getConnection().getServiceName());

            if (data.getRows() != null)
            {
                UserInfoDtl contactDetail = new UserInfoDtl(context);

                for(int i=0;i<data.getRows().size();i++)
                {

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    String Name = data.getRows().get(i).getValues("Name").toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                    String Jid = data.getRows().get(i).getValues("jid").toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                    String Email = data.getRows().get(i).getValues("Email").toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                    String Status = "";
                    values.put(contactDetail.NAME,Name);
                    values.put(contactDetail.JID,Jid);
                    values.put(contactDetail.STATUS,Status);
                    values.put(contactDetail.EMAIL,Email);
                    //  contactDetail.deleteTable();
                    if(!contactDetail.isUserExist(Jid))
                        contactDetail.insert(values);
                    Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(myXMPP.getConnection());
                    /*Presence availability = roster.getPresence(Jid);
                    myXMPP.getConnection().sendStanza(availability);
                    Presence.Mode userMode = availability.getMode();
                    int flag = retrieveState_mode(availability.getMode(),availability.isAvailable());
                    Log.e(Jid,availability.isAvailable()+"");*/
                    try
                    {
                        Presence availability = roster.getPresence(Jid);
                        myXMPP.getConnection().sendStanza(availability);
                        Presence.Mode userMode = availability.getMode();
                        int flag = retrieveState_mode(availability.getMode(),availability.isAvailable());
                        Log.e(Jid,availability.getType()+"");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        android.util.Log.e("tag", "unable to add contact: ", e);
                    }

                }

                /*Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(myXMPP.getConnection());
                Presence availability = roster.getPresence(myXMPP.getConnection().getUser());
                Log.e("Status" , availability.getType()+"");*/


                /*Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                    Presence presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
                    Log.e("Entry",entry+"");
                    Log.e("IsAvailable ",""+presence.isAvailable());
                    Log.e("Status" , ""+presence.getStatus());
                }*/




            }
            return true;

        }
        catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e)
        {
            if(e.getMessage().contains("Already Logged in"))
            {
                Log.e("Messaging Service","Already Logged in "+ myXMPP.getConnection().getUser());
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                ERRORMSG = e.getMessage();
                return false;
            }
        }

//-------------------------------------------------------------
public static int retrieveState_mode(Presence.Mode userMode, boolean isOnline)
    {
        int userState = 0;
        /** 0 for offline, 1 for online, 2 for away,3 for busy*/
        if(userMode == Presence.Mode.dnd) {
            userState = 3;
        } else if (userMode == Presence.Mode.away || userMode == Presence.Mode.xa) {
            userState = 2;
        } else if (isOnline) {enter code here
            userState = 1;
        }
        return userState;
    }
```

Comment: I got half answer by using RosterListener, while another user login at that time i will get whether user is online or not. But I can't get all online user at the time of login in my app.

Comment: "All online users" is not a core XMPP spec. With XMPP, you can just force all users to be in each other rosters and use Presence as you did or, in alternative with Openfire only (it's not a standard spec), you can create an Openfire GROUP and put all users in a common group and user Presence again this group.

Comment: So as per your concern I should create a group first, then add all users to that group. Creation of this group by using MultiUserChat, am I right? @MrPk

Comment: No, group is not groupchat. You can have a Group in a Roster (like "Friends" in Skype) while Roster it's designed to have a contact list (this is a core Xmpp Specification). With this method your effort it's synchronize any User-Roster with current users (as example, against a Jabber Search looking for *). Another way it's to create an Openfire's Group (Ex: AllUserGroup) and subscribe this Group. This is an OF's feature, your effert will be to subscribe this group to each already existing user and for newly registered users. I have not any working example to show, sorry.